# separate dictionary in multiple json files

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, merge

I have multiple json files. I merge the files in a unique dictionary.
What I want, is to save this dictionary back to this json files, maintaining the structure.

Imagine to have this files:

```
    dict_common.json
    {
      "common": {
        "subcommon1_dict": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2
        },
        "subcommon1_list": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      }
    }
```

```
dict_var1.json
{
  "var1": {
    "subvar1_dict": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    },
    "subvar1_list": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
dictmerge.py
    import collections
    import json
    def dict_merge(dct, merge_dct, add_keys=True):
        # from: https://gist.github.com/angstwad/bf22d1822c38a92ec0a9
        """ Recursive dict merge. Inspired by :meth:``dict.update()``, instead of
        updating only top-level keys, dict_merge recurses down into dicts nested
        to an arbitrary depth, updating keys. The ``merge_dct`` is merged into
        ``dct``.

        This version will return a copy of the dictionary and leave the original
        arguments untouched.

        The optional argument ``add_keys``, determines whether keys which are
        present in ``merge_dict`` but not ``dct`` should be included in the
        new dict.

        Args:
            dct (dict) onto which the merge is executed
            merge_dct (dict): dct merged into dct
            add_keys (bool): whether to add new keys

        Returns:
            dict: updated dict
        """
        dct = dct.copy()
        if not add_keys:
            merge_dct = {
                k: merge_dct[k]
                for k in set(dct).intersection(set(merge_dct))
            }

        for k, v in merge_dct.items():
            if (k in dct and isinstance(dct[k], dict)
                    and isinstance(merge_dct[k], collections.Mapping)):
                dct[k] = dict_merge(dct[k], merge_dct[k], add_keys=add_keys)
            else:
                dct[k] = merge_dct[k]

        return dct
    def createdictfromjsonfiles(files):
        dict = {}
        for f in files:
            with open(f) as file:
                dict = dict_merge(dict, json.load(file))
        return dict
```

```
main.py
    import json
    from dictmerge import createdictfromjsonfiles
    def printdict(d):
        print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    print('Merge dict..')
    mydict = createdictfromjsonfiles(['dict_common.json', 'dict_var1.json'])
    printdict(mydict)

    print('Edit dict..')
    mydict['common']['subcommon1_dict']['a'] = 999
    mydict['var1']['subvar1_list'].append(999)
    printdict(mydict)
```

Now I want to separate mydict and save the value in original json file.
I'm trying to iterate over the mydict, check if the key exist in the json file and if true save the value in the json, but I have no idea on how to structure the code.

```
    separate(mydict, ['dict_common.json', 'dict_var1.json'])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand quite thoroughly what you need, but try this:

```py
def separate(merged, originals):
    separated = [{} for _ in range(len(originals))]

    for sep, org in zip(separated, originals):
        for key, val in merged.items():
            if key in org:
                if type(org[key]) != type(val):
                    raise RuntimeError("Types changed, not sure what to do")
                if isinstance(org[key], dict):
                    sep[key] = separate(val, [org[key]])[0]
                else:
                    sep[key] = val
    return separated
```

It doesn't deal with reading/writing files, because it needs to recurse, but you can deal with that on your own elsewhere I believe.